# Select the value of the attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<Surcharge>
  <Rentalplus desc="Rental plus">75.00</Rentalplus> 
  <Gasket desc="Seals and gasket">50.00</Gasket>
  <WearandTear desc"Wear and Tear">100.00</WearandTear>
</Surcharge>
```

from the above xml i want to extract the "desc". keep in mind i have different tag names under the  node.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want just to select the attributes (XPath issue)or do you also want to output them as a sequence (XSLT issue)?

Answer (score 2):

How about a minimalist solution ?

```
//@desc
```

Or more precise

```
/Surcharge//@desc
```

Or even more precise

```
/Surcharge/*[self::Rentalplus|self::Gasket|self::WearandTear]/@desc
```

Comment: I don't think one can call "please look through the whole tree" expression "minimalist" :))

Comment: @Flack, that's quite right.  One could argue that lazy  programmers put more work on the machine.

Comment: @Alejandro. I trust you. But still I'd like to know.  Can't see any edit actually.

Comment: OK I can see it now.  Thx.  I knew there was better than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/@desc"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Exploits built-in rules. Result will be:

```
Rental plusSeals and gasketWear and Tear
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
//@desc
```

See syntax from the w3schools site http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: //@desc works, thanks guys, i tried so many different things but was not working

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

`/*/*/@desc`

This selects all `desc` attributes of all children of the top element of the XML document.

**Never use the `//` abbreviation when the structure of the document is well-known**. Using the `//` abbreviation may result in significantly slow evaluation, because it causes traversal of the whole XML document.